# Error Label must be first item in peter higginson armlite simulator

Tags: assembly

Im trying to make a stopwatch in the peter higginson armlite simulator but I keep getting the error "Error Label must be first item at line 5" and i cant seem to fix it.
any help is appreciated. I believe im on the right track, I could be wrong however, any additional information is appreciated. Thanks

```
'''  1|      ORIGIN 0x0000
  2|      EXPORT start_stopwatch
  3|      SECTION .data
  4|      message
  5|      DCB "Seconds: "
  6|      DCB 0
  7|      SECTION .text
  8|      seconds RN 0      
  9|      start_time RN 1   
 10|
 11|      _start
 12|      LDR R0, =seconds  
 13|      MOV R1, #0
 14|      STR R1, [R0]
 15|      BL start_stopwatch
 16|      stopwatch_loop
 17|      BL display_seconds
 18|      BL wait_for_key
 19|      CMP R0, #'p'
 20|      BEQ pause_stopwatch
 21|      CMP R0, #'r'
 22|      BEQ resume_stopwatch
 23|      CMP R0, #'s'
 24|      BEQ split_time
 25|      BL continue_stopwatch
 26|      B stopwatch_loop
 27|; Start the stopwatch
 28|      start_stopwatch
 29|      BL get_current_time
 30|      LDR R0, =start_time 
 31|      STR R1, [R0]
 32|      B continue_stopwatch
 33|; Continue the stopwatch
 34|      continue_stopwatch
 35|      BL get_current_time
 36|      LDR R0, =start_time 
 37|      LDR R1, [R0]
 38|      LDR R2, =seconds  
 39|      LDR R3, [R2]
 40|      SUB R3, R3, R1
 41|      STR R3, [R2]
 42|      BX LR
 43|; Pause the stopwatch
 44|      pause_stopwatch
 45|      BL get_current_time
 46|      LDR R0, =start_time 
 47|      STR R1, [R0]
 48|      B stopwatch_loop
 49|; Resume the stopwatch
 50|      resume_stopwatch
 51|      BL get_current_time
 52|      LDR R0, =start_time 
 53|      LDR R1, [R0]
 54|      LDR R2, =seconds  
 55|      LDR R3, [R2]
 56|      SUB R3, R3, R1
 57|      STR R3, [R2]
 58|      BX LR
 59|; Display the split time
 60|      split_time
 61|      LDR R0, =seconds 
 62|      LDR R1, [R0]
 63|      BL display_seconds
 64|      B stopwatch_loop
 65|; Get the current time
 66|      get_current_time
 67|      LDR R1, =0xFFFFFFF0 
 68|      LDR R0, [R1]     
 69|      BX LR
 70|; Display the number of seconds
 71|      display_seconds
 72|      LDR R0, =message 
 73|      BL put_string
 74|      MOV R0, R1        
 75|      BL put_dec
 76|      BL put_newline
 77|      BX LR
 78|; Wait for a key press
 79|      wait_for_key
 80|      LDR R0, =0xFFFFFFF8 
 81|      wait_loop
 82|      LDR R1, [R0]    
 83|      CMP R1, #0
 84|      BEQ wait_loop
 85|; Output a string to the console
 86|      put_string
 87|      STR R0, [R7, #4]  
 88|      MOV R0, #1        
 89|      MOV R1, #0        
 90|      SWI "PutString"  
 91|      BX LR
 92|; Output a decimal value to the console
 93|      put_dec
 94|      STR R0, [R7, #4]  
 95|      MOV R0, #1       
 96|      SWI "PutDec"      
 97|      BX LR
 98|; Output a newline character to the console
 99|      put_newline
100|      LDR R0, =0x0A    
101|      MOV R1, #1        
102|      SWI "PutChar"    
103|      BX LR
104|      END
```

'''

Comment: Does it require a label for every source line that has a DCB?  Like `message: dcb "Seconds: ", 0`?  Is all your code indented to the right, even labels?  That's very hard to read, normally we'd intent labels all the way to the left, with instructions indented one tab stop to the right.  e.g. [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965) discusses indentation and coding style and shows an example that I think is readable.

Comment: Anyway, *some* assemblers are picky about indentation, and use that to distinguish label  (no indent) vs. instruction (indented), instead of other things like a `:` after the label name, or simply not recognizing it as a mnemonic (which is bad since typoed instructions with no operands get parsed as defining a lable).  I don't know about the one you're using.